# Time zone conversion in a Laravel-based API app

Tags: laravel, api, timezone

I have a simple, yet difficult problem :-). I am building an API-based app in Laravel.
The app's users will be from different time zones.

Question: How can I handle this properly?

What I did so far:

- in app.php I set 'timezone' to 'UTC'
- my users table has a timezone column
- I use camroncade/timezone package

As far as I understand the docs of the aforementioned package, I should now convert all datetimes that are fetched from the database to the user's timezone and then return the converted time. Also, when users send datetimes to the server (in their timezone), the server should convert it back to UTC and store it in the database.

This makes totally sense. However, the drawback is that I need to find all points where times are transferred to/from the server and intercept those with a time conversion. Additionally, with this solution, how do I convert the laravel-generated create and update timestamps? Is there really no better approach?

Solutions I could think of:

- a possible solution is to only work with UTC on server side and use client side logic (e.g. in an iOS app) to convert to/from the user's local timezone. This would mean that from the API on backwards there are only UTC timestamps.
- another solution could be to install some kind of middleware that intercepts all api communication and does the conversion. However, I have no idea how to do that and it would certainly generate lots of overhead.

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks fpr your ideas,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a whole lot about Laravel, but I do know about time zones and application development.  I can say that in general, you should not try to convert for time zones uniformly, but should consider time zone as an input parameter to business logic when conversion is needed.

By analogy, consider if you weren't talking about time, but about money.  Each user has a different currency.  Would you really want to apply the logic of currency conversion to all money values coming in and out of your system?  Sure, you can, but what if values are accepted in one currency and need to be displayed in another?  Or what if the currency exchange rate changes?  By applying conversions outside of the business logic, you've made code easier at the expense of locking yourself out of features and possibly creating bugs that are subtle and difficult to diagnose.